# Refresh RecyclerView after adding a new element - Android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In my `MainActivity` I have a `RecyclerView` and a `Button`.
When the button is clicked, a new activity is launched in which there's a form to fill. After the user finish to fill the all fields, it has to be pressed a button to save the new element. If everything is correct, the user is redirect to another Activity while in background the new element is added to the list of object and saved with `Shared Preferences`.
When I get back to the `MainActivity` how can I get the new elements?
I tried to retrive the new list by overriding  the `onResume` method, but it did not work out.
Thanks in advance

**EDIT :**

MainActivity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //GET: data source for the array list
    SetDataSource();
    if (travelCards == null) {
        travelCards = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //...
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SaveDataSource();
}

private void SaveDataSource() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(DataKey.DATA_SOURCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(travelCards);
    editor.putString(DataKey.SHARED_PREF_CARD_LIST, json);
    editor.apply();
}

private void SetDataSource() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(DataKey.DATA_SOURCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString(DataKey.SHARED_PREF_CARD_LIST, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<TravelCard>>() {
    }.getType();
    travelCards = gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

Comment: Share your Main Activity code.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan which part? The one where I save the list and I retrive it?

Comment: Yeah. It will be helpful to analyse.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan I added the code, check it out

Comment: where is the reference to the RecyclerView and its Adapter?

Comment: You need to use  `HashSet <>` to save list of new items to shared preference with a key. The method you are using will just update the already existing value of your key in preference. See this answer on [how to save HashSet in Shared Preference] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try, I found out how to update the `RecyclerView`.
In my `MainActivity` I override the `onResume()` method and I make execute this method:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    UpdateDataSource();
}
```

And this is the `UpdateDataSource()` method :

```
private void UpdateDataSource() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(DataKey.DATA_SOURCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString(DataKey.SHARED_PREF_CARD_LIST, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<TravelCard>>() {
    }.getType();
    //Save the new list retrieved from the SharedPref into a temporary ArrayList
    ArrayList<TravelCard> temp = gson.fromJson(json, type);
    //I copy the new list into my main list
    travelCards = temp;
    //I set the new list in the RecyclerView Adapter
    mAdapter.setTravelCards(temp);
    //Notify the adapter that  the data set has been changed
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```